# Using ByRef for values in an array VB Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have come across a problem in some code that I am working on that I have refined down to the following for illustrative purposes.

Say I define the following string and function:

```vb
Public Property Main.Priority As Integer = 0

Public Sub test(ByRef objs As Array)
    For Each obj As Object In objs
        obj = 1
        MsgBox(obj)
    Next
End Sub
```

I then want to call the function as follows:

```vb
test({Main.Priority})
MsgBox(Main.Priority)
```

This gives `1` in the first message box and then `0` in the second.

On the other hand if I do the following:

```vb
Public Property Main.Priority As Integer = 0

Public Sub test(ByRef obj As integer)
    obj = 1
    MsgBox(obj)
End Sub
```

and call again in the same way:

```vb
test({Main.Priority})
MsgBox(Main.Priority)
```

I get `1` and `1`. How can I use `ByRef` with an array to get the desired functionality?

I am using an array as I will be doing multiple in one go going forward.

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict.  `Object` does not have a Text property (`obj.Text`).

Comment: It is this line of code that is not working:                 If obj.GetType() Is GetType(System.String) Then
                    obj = (dr(Cols(Array.IndexOf(Objs, obj)))).ToString()
                    MsgBox(obj)

Comment: The obj.text is working perfectly for the text box and tiles